# To Display Excel Spreadsheet with Charts on Websites

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Is there anyway to display Excel Spreadsheet with charts (Live, does not need to be editable)  on Websites?

Currently I have some Excel reports with charts. I am building a website to display these spreadsheet data. The spreadsheet doesn't need to be editable.  But I want it to be displayed right away, instead of a link downloading it locally every time and open it.

Is there anyway easy way I can do this?

**Some methods that I have researched but would not work in my case:**

1. Google Doc
2. Saving as html output in excel (I want it to be automatically. All the spreadsheet generation/ HTML code creation would be in linux)
3. Sharepoint

Thanks!

Comment: How about exporting the charts / sheets as `.jpg` from Excel? This can be even made part of the `Workbook_BeforeClose` or `Workbook_BeforeSave` event so that all charts and sheets get exported to a particular file-share when the file is saved or closed. Furthermore, you'd benefit from increased security by using a file format (for the exchange between Excel and the website) which is known not to contain viruses and less likely to trigger other security leaks.

Comment: I thought about this. But the problem with this will be I have a lot of rows in the spreadsheets. Converting the spreadsheet to image will make it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to utilize `Excel Services` for that purpose.

> Prerequisite: [Excel Services service application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms546696(v=office.14).aspx) has to be configured

### Prepare excel data

Assume the following excel file

[image]

that contains the following items in the workbook:

- table (how to [Create or delete an Excel table in a worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961897(v=office.14).aspx))
- chart

**Important:** 
Before uploading file into SharePoint library, go to `File -> Browse View Options ->  choose Items in the Workbook` as demonstrated below. Then save file and upload it into SharePoint `Documents` library.

[image]

Once the excel file is uploaded into `Documents` library the chart could be rendered in browser using the following endpoint:

```
Url: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Documents/sample.xlsx/Model/Charts('Chart1')
Method: GET
```

**Results**

Display chart on page via `ScriptEditor`/ContentEditor web part

```
Content: <img src="/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Documents/sample.xlsx/Model/Charts(%27Chart1%27)" alt=""/>
```

[image]

**References**

- [Using the Excel Services 2010 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961897(v=office.14).aspx)